# Spring data Rest returns http 500 when accessing table with data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-rest

I am trying to set up spring-data-rest services. I am using spring-data-rest with hibernate in eclipse. Services work fine (returning HAL + JSON) as long as I have no data in table I am trying to get data from.

When I try to get response from table with data in it, I get blank page in browser, eclipse shows only hibernate query but no exception is shown, and only in curl I get error 500 with no additional info:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /test/categories HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 06:55:22 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

This is my spring-data-rest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans 
    ...namespaces..>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/>
        
        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.test" />
        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbcDataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mammsoft.dal.hibernate" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

And here is class for which I am trying to get data:

```
@Entity
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1023381733544304297L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ProductCategory> productCategories = new HashSet<ProductCategory>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

    public Category() {
    }
    ...
    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

---

---

Here is spring Debug output from failed request:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        productcat0_.category_id as category2_2_0_,
        productcat0_.product_id as product_1_5_0_,
        productcat0_.category_id as category2_5_0_,
        productcat0_.product_id as product_1_5_1_,
        productcat0_.category_id as category2_5_1_,
        productcat0_.cat_order as cat_orde3_5_1_ 
    from
        public.product_category productcat0_ 
    where
        productcat0_.category_id=?
07:51:07.337 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.NullPointerException
07:51:07.342 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.handleNPE(java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

I've traced the exception to `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`, more specifically to this method:

```
public Link getSelfLinkFor(Object instance) {
Assert.notNull(instance, "Domain object must not be null!");

Class<? extends Object> instanceType = instance.getClass();
PersistentEntity<?, ?> entity = repositories.getPersistentEntity(instanceType);

if (entity == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot create self link for %s! No persistent entity found!",
            instanceType));
}

BeanWrapper<Object> wrapper = BeanWrapper.create(instance, null);
Object id = wrapper.getProperty(entity.getIdProperty()); //this line breaks

Link resourceLink = entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(entity.getType(), id);
return new Link(resourceLink.getHref(), Link.REL_SELF);
}
```

Exception is thrown at this line:

```
Object id = wrapper.getProperty(entity.getIdProperty());
```

`bean` property of `wrapper` is set to proper value (`id` and `name` properties are set, while sets are empty) , but `conversionService` is equal to `null`.

Also `idProperty` of `entity` is null, which is causing null pointer exception, when `BeanWrapper` tries to access type.

What I don't know is how to address that issue.

Comment: Do you have the log from the server? If the log doesn't show anything obviously wrong you should look at configuring Spring to output `DEBUG` logging which should be able to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Server log only shows: **127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2015:11:39:04 +0100] "GET /test/categories/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -**

I didn't configure spring to output debug yet, but will do that now

Comment: What version of Spring Data REST are you on? You might wanna debug into `AbstractRepositoryRestController.errorResponse(…)` as you seem to be running into a `NullPointerException` according to the logs. Seems like the `NPE` doesn't hold a message though as that would cause the code path triggered that logs the exception.

Comment: I am using Spring Data REST 2.2.2.RELEASE, I have debugged into Spring classes, and question is updated with new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using wrong `@Id` annotation. I was using `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id` instead of `javax.persistance.Id`

If you are having same problem, check if you are using right annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error because I used annotations on the getters and not on the attributes :

```
//  WRONG
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_user", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}

// OK
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_user", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long _id;
```

I hope this helps.